# How do I lock the country down in Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps, locking, geolocation

How would I make it so you cant drag outside of the UK in google maps? 
Can you lock it down to a certain area, as I'd like to be able to drag around the UK but not outside.

Ta

Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Google Maps API Range Limiting](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm) for an article on how to do this.

The code is all there in [the example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_range.htm).

Comment: Sweet; Forgot to check his site.
Couldn't find an answer in google; I must be suffering keyword retardation today. :op Ta

Answer (score 1):

The earlier accepted answer is deprecated in v3, however, in Feb 2019 Google made available "Restricting bounds of the map" API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-bounds-restriction

Example code locking the bounds to Poland would be:

```
var centerPoland = { lat: 52.407578, lng: 19.393004 };

function initMap() {
  var options = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: centerPoland,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: {
        east:  24.111384999999927,
        north: 54.83666,
        south: 49.002914,
        west: 14.149166000000037
      },
      strictBounds: true
    },
    scaleControl: true
  };
  // Create map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
}
```

Notice how you're unable to zoom out to see the whole country (including neighbours). That's because of `strictBounds: true` Set it to `false` and you can zoom-out, but the panning restriction is still in place.